# GFI Tripping Down Stream

Tags: electrical, kitchens

[image]Hi,
I've been at this for two days and I've run out of idea's, oping for a little guidance. I bought a home in December, built in 2008. The kitchen has 5 outlets along the back splash. In the middle is a GFI outlet, 15 amp plugs 20amp down stream. It feeds two outlets to the left and two outlets to the right. The feed lines are on a 20Amp fuse from the box. When I first moved in the house, I plugged in something in one of the left outlets, it tripped the GFI.

I've bought a new GFI and have been wiring it in. I've got to the point where the two left outlets and the plugs on the GFI work fine. But now if I plug anything into the first right outlet (I've disconnected the second down stream one), even with nothing plugged in to the GFI or two left outlets, it trips the GFI. I've inspected the wires in the boxes as best as I can, I see no breaks in the wires, they look good. I've taken the time to confirm the continuity of the wires for the feeds so I believe I have the correct wires in their correct places. I've replaced the GFI and the two outlets to the right. This is a rough image of the setup. Any idea's?

Comment: It seems to me that the drawing, _at best_, shows us how you _think_ the circuit is configured. Actual photos of the wiring would provide direct, actionable information about how the circuit _is_ actually configured.

Comment: are you familiar with the LOAD terminals and what they do (*other than* give you a place to attach wires)? Do you want to use that functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no surprise that your new receptacle trips the GFI. It's bridging across from the Line terminals (which you've labelled 'Feed') over to the Load terminals.
The GFI is doing its job by detecting an imbalance in the current flowing thru the Load and tripping off.

First thing you need to do is decide if you want your new receptacles to be protected by the GFI or not.
If not, then *both* Black(hot) and White(neutral) wires to your new receptacles *must* be connected on the Line side of your GFI.
If you do want them protected, then *both* wires *must* be connected on the Load side of the GFI.

Comment: "If you do want them protected, then both wires must be connected on the Load side of the GFI." Yes, I would like them protected. I'm sorry, I don't understand, what "both wires"? The black wire on the top right outlet goes to the top?

Comment: "Both wires" means both the back and the white wire. They are a pair and must not be separated. You've drawn them as the black wire to your new receptacle going to the Line/Feed side of the GFI and the white wire going to the Load side of the GFI - that's wrong and is what's causing the GFI to trip. If you want the new receptacles protected, then both the black and white wires must go to the Load side of the GFI.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I moved the top right outlet black wire up to the load on the GFI outlet and it is working correctly. Awesome, thank you so much! I'd attach my updated image, but unable to find out how to.